# Angularjs Code not showing anything

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs, I have designed this code to show food items, but i dont know what  the problem is...It gives nothing as output. I have tried almost everything, but I cant seem to find the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en" ng-app="confusionApp">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head
     content must come *after* these tags -->
<title>Ristorante Con Fusion: Menu</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="styles/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="styles/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row row-content" ng-controller="dishDetailController">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="media-left media-middle">
                        <a href="">
                            <img ng-src={{dish_cmnt.image}} alt="Uthapizza">
                        </a>
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h2 class="media-heading">{{dish_cmnt.name}}
                        <span class="label label-danger">{{dish_cmnt.label}}</span>
                        <span class="badge">{{dish_cmnt.price | currency}}</span></h2>
                        <p>{{dish_cmnt.description}}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1">

        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var app = angular.module('confusionApp',[]);

    app.controller('dishDetailController', function() {

        var dish_cmnt={
                      name:'Uthapizza',
                      image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
                      category: 'mains', 
                      label:'Hot',
                      price:'4.99',
                      description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                       comments: [
                           {
                               rating:5,
                               comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                               author:"John Lemon",
                               date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:4,
                               comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                               author:"Paul McVites",
                               date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:3,
                               comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
                               author:"Michael Jaikishan",
                               date:"2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:4,
                               comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                               author:"Ringo Starry",
                               date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:2,
                               comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                               author:"25 Cent",
                               date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           }

                       ]
                };

        this.dish = dish;

    });

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I can't see `ng-app="confusionApp"` anywhere

Comment: your app has multiple issues, but the one that stands out is that you are defining your `dish_cmnt` as a simple `var`, which will never be accessible to the HTML.  It either needs to be a property of `$scope`, or it needs to be a property of your controller.  You might want to study some more angular examples.

Comment: And even when you added `ngApp`, it will still won't work because you're not declaring your controller using `ng-controller="dishDetailController as vm"` (And then - `{{vm.dish_cmnt.name}}`, etc..)

Comment: also, `this.dish = dish` would throw an error, since `dish` isn't defined anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you were missing `ng-app="confusionApp"` so I added that.

Next, your template didn't have a reference to `dishDetailController` so did that using `ng-controller="dishDetailController as ctrl"` and using `ctrl.dish_cmnt` instead of direct `dish_cmnt`.

Next, `this.dish = dish` was throwing error since `dish` was undefined. Changed that to `this.dish_cmnt = dish_cmnt` since we needed reference to `dish_cmnt` anyway.

That fixed it.

Here's your working code snippet.

```js
var app = angular.module('confusionApp', []);

app.controller('dishDetailController', function() {

  var dish_cmnt = {
    name: 'Uthapizza',
    image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
    category: 'mains',
    label: 'Hot',
    price: '4.99',
    description: 'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
    comments: [{
        rating: 5,
        comment: "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
        author: "John Lemon",
        date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
      },
      {
        rating: 4,
        comment: "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
        author: "Paul McVites",
        date: "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
      },
      {
        rating: 3,
        comment: "Eat it, just eat it!",
        author: "Michael Jaikishan",
        date: "2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
      },
      {
        rating: 4,
        comment: "Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
        author: "Ringo Starry",
        date: "2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
      },
      {
        rating: 2,
        comment: "It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
        author: "25 Cent",
        date: "2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
      }

    ]
  };

  this.dish_cmnt = dish_cmnt;

});
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head
     content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>Ristorante Con Fusion: Menu</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="confusionApp">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row row-content" ng-controller="dishDetailController as ctrl">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="media-left media-middle">
          <a href="">
            <img ng-src={{ctrl.dish_cmnt.image}} alt="Uthapizza">
          </a>
          <div class="media-body">
            <h2 class="media-heading">{{ctrl.dish_cmnt.name}}
              <span class="label label-danger">{{ctrl.dish_cmnt.label}}</span>
              <span class="badge">{{ctrl.dish_cmnt.price | currency}}</span></h2>
            <p>{{ctrl.dish_cmnt.description}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1">

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I tried this but it does not show the content but {{ctrl..dish_cmnt.name}} and all others like this

Comment: @GiteshSawariya what ever you have after `ctrl` should be defined in your controller. So here, if you want to show `ctrl.name`, you gotta have `this.name = "gitesh"` in your controller somewhere

Comment: @GiteshSawariya there might be some other issue then. you can maybe create a fiddle/plunker to reproduce the issue and share it here?